# Cisco VPN Anyconnect Installation via Browser

Tags: browser, installation, vpn, cisco

I tried installing Cisco VPN AnyConnect via Browser but it get stuck at

"Using Sun Java for Installation, Getting the Sun applet.  Please wait... stage.

My environment is Windows 8.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you keep the Java security level to medium (Open Java from Control Panel and go to Security tab) and then try installing the VPN client from the browser this is resolved.